# React 16 HTML attributes with MathML tags

Tags: reactjs, mathml

I'm using MathML markup language to render math equations on my web app. Here's an example of an simple equation which is problematic:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfenced open="[" close="]"><mn>8</mn></mfenced></math>
```

The problem is that React will not treat the attributes of the mfenced tag like we would want to. It treats the "[open](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_open.asp)" attribute as if it was used in a HTML context, so it will not accept its "[" value. React will output the mfenced tag like this:

```
<mfenced open close="]"><mn>8</mn></mfenced>
```

Of course, this breaks the equation in the browser. Is there a way to tell React not to change this attribute?

Comment: what you need is something like an `xml-loader` or xml parser at the babel level so that while compiling it can parse those syntaxes (just a thought)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MathJax React component](https://github.com/mehdisadeghi/react-mathjax-preview) is what you were looking for.

Import the package and fill the math property with some text containing your formals. Wrap TeX in $ or $$ and ASCIImath in `. Paste MathML as is.

Here's an example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import MathJax from 'react-mathjax-preview'

const asciimath = '`sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2`' # Because of the backtick
const math = String.raw`
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
    <menclose notation="circle box">
      <mi> x </mi><mo> + </mo><mi> y </mi>
    </menclose>
  </math>

  $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(-x) = 0$$

  ${asciimath}`

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      math: tex
    }
  render() {
    return <MathJax math={this.state.math} />
  }
}
```

They also have a [more advanced demo](https://github.com/mehdisadeghi/react-mathjax-preview/blob/master/demo/src/index.js) inside the repository.

PS: I saw one [issue related to MathML](https://github.com/mehdisadeghi/react-mathjax-preview/issues/6) in their repo. A workaround is described there.

Comment: Equations in my app are integrated into paragraphs (html p tags), and this package renders the equations into div tags. Div tags are not allowed as children of p tags though... So I finally used a parser ([html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser)) that detects and replace my math tags with span tags which use the react property "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" with the MathML equation as the property value. To convert my MathML equations to string, I used [react-element-to-string](https://github.com/glenjamin/react-element-to-string)

Comment: As I tried to explain, unfortunately, the MathJax React package you suggested to use did not solve my problem. I will post a more detailed answer with my solution soon.